# Regex to match an alphabet + a closing bracket which does not have a matching opening bracket

Tags: python, regex

I would like to match only

a), b) and c)

however my current regex statement also matches all of matching alphabet + ')'.

my current regex statement:

```
(?<!\().*?(\w\))
```

the sentence:

> This is (example a)  a) this is something. b) this is something else.
>   c) this is another thing. This is (example b)  a) this is something.
>   b) this is something else. c) this is another thing.

Expected output: [ 'a)', 'b)', 'c)' ]

Current output: [ 'a)', 'a)', 'b)', 'c)' ]

---

I have also thought of

```
(?<!\(\w+).*?(\w\))
```

but this will not work for my case since I am using Python and the '+' quantifier inside a lookbehind is not valid in Python. So any ideas on a workaround to this is also welcome.

Comment: Your current output differs from the expected output only by the presence of duplicates. Simply convert it to a `set()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alternation pattern that matches either a pair of matching parentheses or a word character followed by a right parenthesis, and then filter out empty matches:

```
list(filter(None, re.findall(r'.*?(?:\([^)]*\)|(\w\)))', s)))
```

so that given:

```
s = 'This is (example a) a) this is something. b) this is something else. c) this is another thing.'
```

it will return:

```
['a)', 'b)', 'c)']
```